# "Register and view you application"

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, spelling

A little bug: I just applied for a job, and the confirmation e-mail contained a link titled "Register and view you application".

I hope Stack Overflow doesn't think I'm an application!

Comment: Cannot reproduce without applying for you job.

Comment: Register and view, you application!

Answer (score 7):

This has been fixed. Thanks for the report.